# add directory name in url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have website called **http://example.com** which is pointing to my **public_html** directory. 
I want my website should work with **http://example.com/cms** URL . And  **http://example.com/cms** should point to **public_html** directory. Is it possible without creating sub directory on website root?

How can I do this with .htaccess ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just create and use this cms directory ?

Comment: Actually, it is not allowed to do. we need to do this with .htaccess rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide any details about the CMS you want to use, I can only provide a generic .htaccess file. If your CMS comes with some special rewrite rules you may have to adapt this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect to /cms if not rewritten internal
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cms(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /cms/$1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite to root directory if URL starts with /cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?cms(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1 [L]
```

Just put this .htaccess file in your **public_html** folder where your CMS is installed. If you call your Website http://example.com you will be redirected (301) to http://example.com/cms and any URL that begins with /cms will internally redirected to your root folder. You do not have to create a /cms subfolder.

I did test this positive on a Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS Server with Apache 2.4.27.

Comment: i have used this code it always shows 404 if i will open url  example.com/cms

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and do have the right to use .htaccess?

Comment: Yes i have mode_rewrite enabled 
also used right .htaccess